# How to override the default_url method for carrierwave in a Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, rails-engines

I have a Rails engine which uses carrierwave and supplies its own default image.

I would like to override this default image in the host application and so need to override the `default_url` method on the uploader.

This doesn't seem to be quite as simple as it seems and I think it may have something to do with how carrierwave unloaders are mounted. Opening the class and adding the new version of the method doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas of how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

*default_url* method can be used to set a default value for the asset if that is not present.

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url(*args)
    "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end
end
```

This will work for all the versions. If you want to set different default values for different versions then you can override this method

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # this will work for all version
  def default_url(*args)
    "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end

  version :thumbnail do
    # this will work for thumbnail version only.
    def default_url(*args)
        "assets/thumb.png"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url) points out that it should be trivial to override the default_url method in the uploader class. In fact, the [default method](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/uploader/default_url.rb#L15) is blank.

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def default_url
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  end
end
```

If this doesn't work, there may be some other issue, like needing to restart your server, or run `bundle clean`, etc.

Comment: "Opening the class and adding the new version of the method doesn't seem to work." (i.e this is exactly what I have already tried)  -- The issue here is understanding how to do this where this method has already been defined in a Rails Engine.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question but it may be helpful to someone so I'll awards the bounty anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for multiple versions instead of version_name use it it like this

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("dashboard/" + [@mounted_as, "file_name.png"].compact.join('_'))
```

in @mounted_as you will get the symbol of the version

example

```
version :person_image
```

@mounted_as will be :person_image

have fun =)

Answer (score -1):

You can override `store_dir` method to change the url of image.

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    'public/my/upload/directory'
  end
end
```

you can find here:

```
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#changing-the-storage-directory
```

Comment: This changes where the uploads are stored, not the default image.